# composer : is there a way to specify a preference order for package repositories?

Tags: php, repository, composer-php

I am working with a package `vendorName/moduleName` (a Magento extension) that is present on [packagist](https://packagist.org/) and on [firegento](http://packages.firegento.com/).

On my `composer.json` file, I have :

```
"require": {
   ....................,
   ...................,
  "vendorName/moduleName":"*"
},
"repositories": [
  ......................,
  ....................,
  {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packages.firegento.com"
  }
],
```

As [Composer is downloaded pre-configured to use packagist.org](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232472/7497291) , the `vendorName/moduleName` is loaded from `packagist`.

**I would like to force `vendorName/moduleName` to be loaded from  `firegento`.**

I tried to add :

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "packagist": false
  },
```

but then, composer will no more search in packagist : that's not what I want.(as there are usefull packages in packagist too...)

I guess I could use

```
composer config --global --unset repositories.packagist
```

and then

```
composer config --global repositories.firegento composer https://packages.firegento.com
composer config --global repositories.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

to add repositories in my prefered order (I'm not sure it works...).

Is there a better/simpler way to achieve my purpose ? I would prefer editing the `composer.json` more than running global config commands but it's maybe not possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well,

I think I found the answer [here](https://github.com/composer/satis/issues/407#issuecomment-289915352):

> Repository candidates are, in the end, only evaluated by their order of definition. Packagist is internally added as the last one by definition (though you can disable that) to ensure local copies are always preferred, if allowed by resolver settings.

That means that if I define the `firegento` repo in my `composer.json`, then composer will load the package `vendorName/moduleName` in `firegento` before `packagist`. I thought it was the opposite behaviour; I was wrong.

Another helpfull comment [here](https://github.com/composer/satis/issues/407#issuecomment-289682711):

> Order of repository definitions matters. But composer will still search through all repositories regardless, because it could be that a repository that is defined later has a more recent version available of the package you are requiring.

Answer (score 1):

In Composer v2, additional VCS repositories default to "canonical," meaning that Composer will not try to retrieve from Packagist a requirement found in the custom repository.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/repository-priorities.md

This default will fulfill the original goal in this thread, that of *only* retrieving from the custom repository, not Packagist.

If you *do* want to be able to retrieve from Packagist but have your custom repository have higher precedence, make the repository non-canonical:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/repository-priorities.md#making-repositories-non-canonical