# Prefer packagist over external composer repository when installing packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I required a package with composer which is available from packagist and another composer repository I defined in my `composer.json`. Composer installed the version from the other repository which makes sense after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49190694/10924593).

However, I want to install the package explicitly from packagist, since the version in the other repository is outated.

Is this possible?

A solution I've considered was to add the repo's github repository also as composer vcs repository but I think that is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up requiring a specific (newer) version of the package, which I knew was available from packagist, but not from the other composer repository.
This seems to work but is IMHO also more a workaround than a proper solution. It also means having a pinned version in my `composer.json`.